# Team Services Run Powershell on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, tfs, virtual-machine, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

So I want to run a powershell script located on my azure virtual machine via the task run powershell on target machine within the release tool in team services.

However I get the following error

System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: An object at the specified path C:\Users\ADMIN~1.USE does not exist. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: An object at the specified path C:\Users\ADMIN~1.USE does not exist.

2016-08-31T10:21:37.0192754Z ##[error]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have also ran Enable-PSremoting  on the virtual machine

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: How do you specify PowerShell script file and machine in Run PowerShell On Target machine task? Could you ping that virtual machine from VSTS agent machine? What's the result if you run script through PowerShell from VSTS agent machine (Invoke-command) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/11/16/enable-powershell-remoting-to-enable-running-commands/

Comment: The machine is specified via the dns name and the script is specified via the path to where it is on the C drive

Comment: Can you configure the virtual machine by following this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/ and then try again.

Comment: I have just tried everything in this example and the example works fine the release task still give me the error

Comment: Are you using an Azure Classic Virtual Machine or Azure Resource Group? Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines

Comment: @user1488692 Based on the error message, the user name is ADMIN~1.USE, what's the if you remove the special character from user name and try to build and release?

Comment: Its using Azure Resource Group

Comment: I dont have any special characters in my user name on the release task. The username is admin.user

Comment: @user1488692 Check the description in the link: If you have an Azure Resource Group already defined in the Azure portal, you must configure it to use the WinRM HTTPS protocol. You need to open port 5986 in the firewall, and install a self-signed certificate.

Comment: I have done both of these

Comment: I am able to transfer files to server no problem

Comment: Does it work if you run the remote powershell script on Azure VM from your own machine manully?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurs if your Virtial Machine's login user name has a dot(**'.'**) character in it. Try with a user name with no dots, which solve the above issue.